# C# to Java rewriting - generic class

Tags: c#, java, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite this C# code into java?

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{

    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

I have problem creating generic class with parameter T in its name. I also don't know, how to solve out parameter, which Java don't support. Anyone who is experienced in both platforms?

Comment: The equivallent of IEnumerable is Iterable. You don't need to write this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `out` here isn't for an `out` parameter in the normal sense - it's expressing the fact that `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T`. That allows you to say, for example:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

Java deals with generic variance very differently, basically. In fact, generics in Java are very different in general - look at the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for a *lot* more detail.

The near-equivalent of `IEnumerable<T>` in Java is [`Iterable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) - you'd be far better off using that than copying `IEnumerable<T>` across. (For example, `Iterable<T>` has language support in Java in the form of the "enhanced for loop".)

Answer (score 0):

Im not an C# coder but following code might work:

```
public interface IEnumerable<T> {
    Iterable<T> getEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: IEnumerable IS Iterable. Theoretically you should return Iterator<T> but the whole thing is pointless since Iterable is already a part of Java